# If the following bijective, injective, both, or neither?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$f:\:\mathbb{R}^{+}\rightarrow\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^{+})$
  defined by $f(x)=\{x^{n}|n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$

Let $f(q)=f(r)$
 , that is $q^{n}=r^{n}$
 , we see that $q=r$
 . Hense, that fuction is injective. Would you have to consider if $n$
  is different in both cases?

Also, is the function surjective?

Comment: What maps to $\{2\}$?

Comment: Contents of $f(x)$ aside, are you aware of [Cantor's diagonal argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_diagonal_argument)?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of hints.  For surjectivity, what maps to the set containing the singleton 2 - i.e $\{2\}$?

For injectivity, try to find *all* numbers that map to

$$\{\ldots,1/4, 1/2, 1, 2, 4, \ldots\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Consider first instead $ℝ → \mathcal{P}(ℝ),\, x ↦ ℤx$ and make a picture of $f(x)$ for $x ∈ ℝ$.
Is this function surjective or injective?

Answer (score 0):

Warning, $f(q)$ is not $q^n$ : $f(q)$ is the set $\{q^{n}|n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ !

- **f is not injective**, because $f(2) = f(1/2)$.
- **f is not surjective**. Let's $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $y \in f(x)$. We have $y^2 \in f(x)$. So for example there is not $x$ such as $f(x) = \{2\}$ (if this would be the case, we would have $4 \in f(x)$ !).